# Length of a conical helix- improper integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

I was trying to solve the following task (no. 2304) from Demidovich:

> Compute the arc length of the conical helix $x=ae^t\cos t,y=ae^t\sin t, z=ae^t$ from the point $(0,0,0)$ to the point $(a,0,a),a>0.$

I'm not sure if my solution as a whole is valid, so I would like to verify it.

$$\begin{aligned}\gamma(t)&:=(ae^t\cos t,ae^t\sin t,ae^t)\\\implies \gamma'(t)&=ae^t(\cos t-\sin t, \cos t+\sin t, 1)\\\implies \|\gamma'(t)\|&=ae^t(1-\sin(2t)+1+\sin(2t)+1)\\&=a\sqrt 3e^t\end{aligned}$$

$(a,0,a)=(ae^t\cos t, ae^t\sin t, ae^t)$ if $t=0.$ I think the origin isn't on the curve and I got the following improper integral $$\begin{aligned}\ell&=\int_{-\infty}^0\|\gamma(t)\|dt\\&=\int_{-\infty}^0a\sqrt 3 e^tdt\\&=a\sqrt 3\int_{-\infty}^0 e^tdt\\&=a\sqrt 3e^t\Big|_{-\infty}^0\\&=a\sqrt 3.\end{aligned}$$

I wasn't quite able to visualize it.

Comment: This is fine. The origin is indeed the limit point as $t\to -\infty$.